# Accidentally messed up URLs

Tags: apache, home-url

So I installed WordPress on my Apache server and I changed the URL in the WordPress Admin Control Panel to `http://website.com/` from `http://website.com/wordpress` and now it's taking me to my old `index.html` I made before I installed WordPress, even though I moved all my old stuff to a backup folder. Now I cannot get back into my WordPress admin CP.

So my question is:

How do I switch the URLs inside the WordPress files instead of the Admin CP (Cause I cannot get to it).

How do I make the WordPress url to `http://website.com/` instead of `http://website.com/wordpress`?

P.S. I didn't include http:// on the links because I can't post more than two links with my rep.

Comment: The only real way to undo what you did, is to use a database client like phpmyadmin to access your database and undo-ing the changes.  Figuring out what table & field to change might be hard.  I think you modified the sites 'siteurl'.  If you have no content, you may want to consider re-installing WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codex has an article on [Changing The Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL), you can edit values in database or override them in config.

To have your site work from root you can either relocate WP there altogether or configure it to support root of the site, while still residing in subdirectory. See [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) on the latter.